# Сортировка символов строки в алфавитном порядке

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

Скрипт в Гугл таблицах мониторит внешние json на предмет изменений конвертируя их в строку, высчитывая hash и если hash изменился пересылает уведомление.

Проблема возникла следующая - порой приходят json с изменившемся порядком элементов, но информация при этом не поменялась, а hash у них соответственно разный.

Пример: json1={name:вася,name:петя} json2={name:петя,name:вася}

Массив может иметь произвольное количество уровней и сортировка по ключам вероятно не пройдет. Созрел вариант костыля после JSON.stringify сделать сортировку всех символов в алфавитном порядке и уже с этой строки брать hash. Как это красивее реализовать на JS/GAS (с языками знаком не достаточно хорошо)?

Возможно есть и другие варианты решение моего вопроса?

Comment: С сортировкой символов можно нарваться на ситуацию, когда `{"name" : "вася"}` и `{"name" : "ясав"}` будут сочтены одинаковыми.

Comment: Именно в моей ситуации это скорее маловероятно, но да!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) В случае именно с такими JSON, как Вы указали в примере - GAS'овское решение `JSON.stringify()` выдаст результат, который скорее всего вы не ожидаете (перезапишет данные по ключу последним значением). Пример:

```
function test2(){
  var json1={"name":"вася","name":"петя"};
  var json2={"name":"петя","name":"вася"};

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(json1)); //выдаст {"name":"петя"}
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(json2)); //выдаст {"name":"вася"}
}
```

2) Если же JSON будут с уникальными значениями, то Ваш костыль будет выглядеть примерно так: (для теста использовалось решение г-на oshliaer для вычисления [hash](https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets#compute-a-hash-string) )

```
function test(){
  var json1={"name":"вася","sname":"петя"};
  var json2={"sname":"петя","name":"вася"};

  var sortedJsonString1 = sortString_(JSON.stringify(json1));
  var sortedJsonString2 = sortString_(JSON.stringify(json2));

  Logger.log(sortedJsonString1); //"""""""",::aaeemmnns{}авепстяя
  Logger.log(sortedJsonString2); //"""""""",::aaeemmnns{}авепстяя
  Logger.log(sortedJsonString1 == sortedJsonString2); //true

  var hash1 = hash_(sortedJsonString1, Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  var hash2 = hash_(sortedJsonString2, Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);

  Logger.log(hash1); //1bed8590421187423857aea7402f5ae70b73a4635601f4067d78acc2bdf04729
  Logger.log(hash2); //1bed8590421187423857aea7402f5ae70b73a4635601f4067d78acc2bdf04729
  Logger.log(hash1 == hash2); //true
}

function sortString_(someString) {
  return someString.split('').sort().join('');
}

function hash_(str, digestAlgorithm, charset) {
  charset = charset || Utilities.Charset.UTF_8;
  digestAlgorithm = digestAlgorithm || 'MD5';
  var digest = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm[digestAlgorithm], str, charset);
  var __ = '';
  for (i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
    var bStr = (digest[i] < 0 ? digest[i] += 256 : digest[i]).toString(16);
    if (bStr.length == 1) bStr = '0' + bStr;
    __ += bStr;
  }
  return __;
}
```

Насколько данный костыль работоспособен - сказать сложно,  без тестов на реальных данных. Я взял для примера JSON с [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) - тоже сработал :

```
var json1 = {
   "firstName": "Иван",
   "lastName": "Иванов",
   "address": {
       "streetAddress": "Московское ш., 101, кв.101",
       "city": "Ленинград",
       "postalCode": "101101"
   },
   "phoneNumbers": [
       "812 123-1234",
       "916 123-4567"
   ]
};
  var json2 = {
   "lastName": "Иванов",
   "firstName": "Иван",
   "phoneNumbers": [
       "812 123-1234",
       "916 123-4567"
   ],
   "address": {
       "streetAddress": "Московское ш., 101, кв.101",
       "city": "Ленинград",
       "postalCode": "101101"
   }
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, вероятно someString.split('').sort().join(''); именно то что надо.

Comment: А вот с хэшем в примере кода сильно мудрено, у меня одной строкой:

var hash=Utilities.base64Encode( Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)));

Comment: НА вкус и цвет фломастеры разные